# My account on Cosmos global instance seems to be running out of space - maybe need to increase quota

Tags: fiware, fiware-cosmos

Trying to run a simple hdfs query failed with:

```
[ms@cosmosmaster-gi ~]$  hadoop fs -ls /user/ms/def_serv/def_servpath
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Insufficient space for shared memory file:
   /tmp/hsperfdata_ms/21066
Try using the -Djava.io.tmpdir= option to select an alternate temp location.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ___/tmp/hsperfdata_ms/21078
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ___.tmp.hsperfdata_ms.21078
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: ___/tmp/hsperfdata_ms/21078.  Program will exit.
```

Any idea how to fix that or increase quota?

Thanks!

ms

Answer (score 0):

Your quota has not been exceeded (see command below), but this was a problem with the cluster. It should be fixed now.

```
$ hadoop fs -dus /user/ms
hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/user/ms  90731
```